# How to optonal delete documents if they exist in mongo db using spring data

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, mongodb-query, spring-data

I want to delete all documents associated with particular facility name and then insert new records of that facility as a list, the problem I have is that if facility name does not exist the query fails to insert new record it only inserts data if facility name exists

This is all what I have

```
Statement org = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet result = org.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM ORGANISATIONS);

for(int i=0; result.length; i++ ) {
Facility facility = new Facility();
Facility.setFacilityId(result.getString(1));
Facility.setFacilityCode(result.getString(2));
Facility.setFacilityName(basename);
visitList.save(facility);
}

result.close();
visits.close();
```

Any help it will be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I'm confused this is tagged as [spring-data-jpa] but talks about MongoDB and seems to be using `MongoTemplate` which is from [spring-data-mongodb] but it also uses SQL.

Comment: When you say "it fails" I assume you get an exception. What is that exception? Please add it to your question, including the full stack trace.

Comment: no exception is being printed however no data is saved @Jens Schauder